# How do I get a key from a single object in the array?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a FirebaseListObservable which is looped through and a single object in the list is passed through, how do I get the key value of the object passed through?

A single instance of the object is passed through to the function when selected and I need to get the key but if I use value.key or value.uid it is undefined.

This is the loop which does through the firebase array

```
<sebm-google-map-marker
*ngFor="let m of markers | async"
(markerClick)="test(m)"
[latitude]="m.lat"
[longitude]="m.lng"
```

>

When clicked on this is the function

```
 test(m){
var things=m;
console.log(m.val());}
```

I want to get the key of the item being passed through

[this is the data being passed and want to get the key for the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBa1X.png)

Comment: please share some code example for others to understand

Comment: @abeyaz There you go thanks for telling me

Comment: Could you show the code that fills the `markers` property of your component? I think one solution could be to sotre the **key** of the item stored in the **marker** object when you load it from the Firebase back-end.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the keys and then use the keys to loop through the collection:

First make an array of your keys (probably do this in a subscribe block since it looks like an observable in your code):

```
markerKeys = Object.keys(markers);
```

Then use the keys to loop:

```
<sebm-google-map-marker
  *ngFor="let mKey of markerKeys"
  (markerClick)="test(markers[mKey])"
  [latitude]="markers[mKey].lat"
  [longitude]="markers[mKey].lng"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Eeks33 is right, but since markers is not an collection but instead an Observable of an collection you canot treat it as collection.

try

```
const addKeys = (collection => Object.keys(collection)
                                     .map(key => collection[key] = key));
const markersWithKeys = markers.map(addKeys);
```

then you should be able to iterate in your template over `markersWithKeys` where every item now has also a key property.

```
<sebm-google-map-marker
*ngFor="let m of markersWithKeys | async"
(markerClick)="test(m)"
[latitude]="m.lat"
[longitude]="m.lng"
```

Within your clickhandler you should be able to access the key like so:

```
test(m) {
    console.log(m.key);
}
```